# How to get the value of the textbox which created dynamically with the Raduploader in code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I use the [AsyncUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/additionalfields/defaultcs.aspx)

---

```
 <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="rada_attach" OnClientFileUploaded="onClientFileUploaded"
                                MultipleFileSelection="Disabled" InitialFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileInputsCount="1"
                                Width="100%" />
```

---

```
function onClientFileUploaded(radAsyncUpload, args) {
    var row = args.get_row(),
        inputName = radAsyncUpload.getAdditionalFieldID("TextBox"),
        inputType = "text",
        inputID = inputName,
        input = createInput(inputType, inputID, inputName),
        label = createLabel(inputID),
        br = document.createElement("br");

    row.appendChild(br);
    row.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(label);

}

function createInput(inputType, inputID, inputName) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");

    input.setAttribute("type", inputType);
    input.setAttribute("id", inputID);
    input.setAttribute("name", inputName);

    return input;
}
```

---

I want to access the textbox (which created dynamically) in .cs.

How to do that ?

---

The Full Answer :

```
var $ = $telerik.$;

function onClientFileUploaded(radAsyncUpload, args) {
    var $row = $(args.get_row());
    var inputName = radAsyncUpload.getID("TextBox");
    var inputType = "text";
    var inputID = inputName;
    var input = createInput(inputType, inputID, inputName);
    var label = createLabel(inputID);
    $row.append("<br/>");
    $row.append(label);
    $row.append(input);
}

function createInput(inputType, inputID, inputName) {
    var input = '<input type="' + inputType + '" id="' + inputID + '" name="' + inputName + '" />';
    return input;
}

function createLabel(forArrt) {
    var label = '<label for=' + forArrt + '>info: </label>';
    return label;
}
```

---

```
   foreach (UploadedFile UF in rada_attach.UploadedFiles)
                {
                    if (UF.GetFieldValue("TextBox") != null)
                    {
                        OBJ.File_name = UF.GetFieldValue("TextBox");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OBJ.File_name = UF.GetName();
                    }
```

Comment: It was created on the client side, not the server side.  CS won't be able to touch it unless it's posted back.

Comment: Do you save generated id on server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion documentation is well clear. Check the Description tab on page you refer on.  You can access value of dynamic textboxes with code below on postback:

```
if (rada_attach.UploadedFiles.Count > 0) {
    for (var index = 0; index < rada_attach.UploadedFiles.Count; ++index) {
        var textBoxValue = rada_attach.UploadedFiles[index].GetFieldValue("TextBox");
    }
}
```

BTW, this scenario is well-dcoumented here: [Adding Information to Uploaded Files](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-adding-information.html)

Comment: I try  this :
`foreach (UploadedFile UF in rada_attach.UploadedFiles)
                {
                    byte[] file = AttachDAL.ReadFully(UF.InputStream);

                    if (UF.GetFieldValue("TextBox") != null)
                    {
                        OBJ.File_name = UF.GetFieldValue("TextBox");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OBJ.File_name = UF.GetName();
                    }`

Comment: but `UF.GetFieldValue("TextBox")` is always null

Comment: There is mismatch in documentation. Here s suggested to use `radAsyncUpload.getID` function instead of `radAsyncUpload.getAdditionalFieldID` Try it

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the `Request.Form` values (that were in the posted form) on postback and perform a check on all the fields that were posted back.

I am guessing that you won't know the name/id of the textbox if it was created on the client-side dynamically? Note that it would be the `name` of the form field that the `Request` object in .cs would see.

Only once you have posted back can you access that value in the .cs